# Stack order of siblings with absolute and relative positions respectively in a parent positioned relatively?

Tags: css

I found out that if we put two siblings one with absolute position and the other one with relative in a containing block with relative position, then the relatively positioned sibling will cover the absolutely positioned one. But why?